# Does being isomorphic to a full subcategory imply being isomorphic to the catgeory

Tags: category-theory

Suppose that $C'$ is a full subcategory of $C$ but some objects and arrows of $C$ are not in $C'$. If $C'$ is isomorphic to category $D$, does this imply that $C$ is not isomorphic to $D$?

If not, what properties of $C'$ or $C$ would make this implication hold (if they are still of the same size).

Comment: What you’re really asking is whether $C$ can be isomorphic to $C’$. There is no need to mention $D$.

Answer (score 4):

What about $C = (\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}, \leq)$, viewed as a category, and $C' = (\{1,2,3,\ldots\},\leq)$.

Then $C'$ is a full subcategory of $C$, which doesn't contain the object $0$ or any of the arrows sourced at $0$, yet $C$ and $C'$ are isomorphic as posets, thus as categories.

Of course, they're also [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories) as categories, which is frequently a more useful notion of two categories being "the same".

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Ah sorry I posted basically the same answer right after you

Comment: Thanks! My question was not complete (has been changed). Do you know under what conditions would this implication hold (if $C$ and $C'$ are still of the same size)?

Comment: I'm not sure of any neat conditions which give you what you want. Already for posets it seems like a hard question to understand when $C$ is not isomorphic to any proper subposet. Indeed, even for _linear orders_ the problem is complicated! See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131933/is-it-possible-to-construct-an-infinite-subset-of-bbb-r-that-is-not-order-iso), for instance.

Comment: Thanks! The way I thought about this and the example you gave treat functors as analogous as functions. But I guess it is not the case that for any small categories $C$ and $D$ and a functor $F:C\rightarrow D$, if the sets of $C$-objects and of $D$-objects are equinumerous and $Hom(c_1,c_2), Hom(Fc_1 ,Fc_2)$ are also equinumerous, then there's an inverse of $F$ which makes $C$ and $D$ isomorphic. Am I right?

Comment: If $F$ witnesses the equinumerousness, in the sense that $F$ is a bijection on objects, and for each pair of objects $F$ is also a bijection on arrows, then $F$ must have an inverse. Basically the same proof that a bijective group homomorphism is an isomorphism works. A "bijective" functor in this sense will also be an isomorphism of categories. If this isn't obvious, you should try proving it!

Answer (score 3):

Take the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ viewed as a category with only identities for arrows, and consider the full subcategory $2\mathbb{N}$.